# Download part of a playlist from YouTube using youtube-dl

Tags: command-line, youtube, youtube-dl

How can I use **youtube-dl** to download a given playlist from YouTube but starting with a given video? For example I want to download a YouTube playlist by starting from the 5th video and not the first one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Run `youtub-dl --help` to see available options.

Comment: @mikewhatever can you explain why it's a problem that can't be reproduced, that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time?

Comment: @Exeleration-G Yes, I can. :~)

Answer (score 9):

From the `man` pages:

```
--playlist-start NUMBER          playlist video to start at (default is 1)
```

So in your case: `youtube-dl --playlist-start 5 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-qBHd6_LXWaytjEA5obaZz1syWcUGY0Q`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ youtube-dl -cit --playlist-start 5 "playlist link"
```

example :

```
$ mkdir tuts
$ cd tuts
$ youtube-dl -cit --playlist-start 5 "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL86CB94C68F628D19"
```

> playlist Ubuntu Tutorial: Collected 21 video ids (downloading 17 of
>   them)

more info

```
$ youtube-dl --help
```